# Thread.Join() causes processing of window messages in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, opengl

I found some strange behavior in WPF Dispatcher mechanism. Let me quickly explain the application:

I have a WPF window with several OpenTK OpenGLControls hosted inside WindowsFormsHosts. During the OnPaint event of an OpenGLControl, I do the rendering of the corresponding 3D scene.

During rendering it may happen that I need to wait for another thread to finish. The problem now is that during the call of Thread.Join(), the Dispatcher processes for other window messages for whatever reasons. This is causing problems in my application and I want to disable / prevent / understand the behavior. Do you know how this is possible?

In my application, this causes an unexpected OpenGl context switch as the paint event of a different OpenGl context is processed while processing the paint event of another OpenGL Control.

This is the callstack of the application, maybe this helps:
[Callstack http://public.virtualmischa.de/bugs/paintevent-while-join.png](http://public.virtualmischa.de/bugs/paintevent-while-join.png)

Thank you

Michael

Comment: From what i understand, your problem is that the Dispatcher is continuing to process messages while you are waiting on a Thread.Join()?

Comment: yes, exactly. Any other way to prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Thread.Join` [is known](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828988) to pump more messages than `WaitHandle.WaitOne` normally does.

Instead of:

```
_thread.Join();
```

Try this:

```
Task.Run(() => _thread.Join()).Wait();
```

This will move `_thread.Join()` from the UI thread to a `ThreadPool` thread, where there's nothing to pump. It should prevent pumping on the UI thread.

It's possible to use timeout, too:

```
Task.Run(() => _thread.Join(timeout)).Wait();
```

Comment: Okay, thank you for your answer. 
Unfortunately, I cannot force my application be have as expected using MTAThread attribute as I am using Winforms.
I hate all this magic... So I need to use a different locking mechanism as well or surround every locking operation with a Task.Run(() => {}).Wait(). Pretty annoying.

Comment: @BikingGlobetrotter, you don't need `MTAThread` here. What did not work with this solution, specifically?

Comment: Actually, I would like to avoid your snippet, for me it looks like a workaround that is the reason I would like to use MTAThread. 
There are 2 consequence of this behavior:

1. I need to workaround every lock inside our library function that uses lock(this){} because the Monitor.TryEnter is also affected by this behavior

2. Any code that uses lock(this){} / Thread.Join that is assumed to work in a single thread environment need to be checked. The behavior results in a hidden multithreading

Comment: @BikingGlobetrotter, I'm not sure I follow, perhaps because I don't have a clear picture of the threading model of your app. You *cannot* use WinForms/WPF/Graphics APIs on an MTA thread. I'm not sure about OpenTK /OpenGL but I think they also require an STA threads. And `Thread.Join` *will* be pumping if called from an STA thread. If you want to block pumping, you'll have to call `Thread.Join` from a non-STA thread, as done above.